# Is there a way emulating real firmware using simcs?

Tags: simics

I am trying to emulate real firmware using simcs.
I typed the following commands.

```
simics>run-command-file targets/qsp-x86/firststeps.simics bios_image=targets/real_firmware.bin
simics>run
```

After the command, there is no change on  command line, board.mb.gpu.vga and board.mb.sb.com[0].
I think this is caused by there is no info about real firmware. But I can not find any docu or comments about this problem.

Is there a way to run real firmware on Simics or other commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run almost any kind of software on Simics. Just do it as you would on real hardware. Simics need to know where to "start" though.
Best regards
Simon @IAmIntel